# Custom Action call cmd, error code 1

Tags: cmd, wix, custom-action

I have to call the cmd during the installation and when i run the installer all looks working well. But it is not like it looks.

In the log there is following line:

"CustomAction CMDInstallKey returned actual error code 1 but will be translated to success due to continue marking"

and even the cmd call don´t work. For understanding, the cmd pops up and the text goes into, but it do not work, and the error is quite strange, too. I have found nothing in the internet.

My code is this:

```
<CustomAction Id='CMDInstallKey' Directory='INSTALLLOCATION' 
Execute='immediate'ExeCommand='cmd.exe /c &quot; .\PontefixEncryptionTool 
-install WinInstaller .\keycontainer.pkxml del .\keycontainer.pkxml' Return='ignore' />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='CMDInstallKey' After='InstallFinalize'></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Is it "Pontefix" or "Pontifex"?

Comment: There is no closing quote in command. If `del` is a cmd command, it should be separated from previous with ampersand. Have you see [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/21/from-msi-to-wix-part-5-custom-actions.aspx)?

Comment: Oh, thanks for remembering, I forgot it, and add it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it is better to use QtExecCmdLine?